# Unable to Set Screen Resolution(1920 * 1080) in Ubuntu 20.0.4

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, display, display-resolution, screen

[image]

I recently purchased a 24" LG PC. when I start my pc it shows a warning that your screen resolution is not currently set to 1920*1080. I try to solve this warning by using a terminal. but can't solve this issue.
I set 1920 * 1080 new screen resolution using the below command
cvt 1920 1080

```
cvt 1920 1080
sudo xrandr -0-newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

After applying a new resolution still getting issues.  Also, the screen does not fully fit in the monitor.

[image: click here to view attached screenshot]

I also installed Nvidia Driver but still not working.

Comment: You can try changing between different resolutions. If you find any suitable resolution then use it instead.

Comment: You can also use [this snap](https://snapcraft.io/install/custom-screen-resolution/ubuntu) to look for an adequate resolution.

Comment: @someone I installed snap but could you guide me more.

Comment: Ok that is great. Can you post a screenshot of what you can see?

Comment: Also, as I can see, you may have issues with (1): Screen resolution: It is probably a 1900 x 1200 pixels Resolution. (2): Zoom factor: If the resolution is correct then probably zoom factor is really low.

Comment: @someone https://ibb.co/Ns7Y1Sr   Please see this image

Comment: Great! I'm sorry for responding late. Ok, as I mentioned in my earlier comment, can you change the resolution to 1900x1200 pixels and see if it works. If not, then also try increasing the zoom factor of the resolution .